# Use of "It is to report that"

Tags: phrase-meaning

When do we use "It is to report that"?

If I am to report something, can I say "It is to report that"?

Comment: No. In english, I have never heard the phrase 'It is to report that?' Instead, I have heard, 'Can I report that?' (for something you don't know whether or not you'll report) 'I reported that' (for something you already reported) and 'I will report that.' (for something you will report in the future.)

Comment: Can I say "This is to report that" instead?
What should  I say if I want to express that I am to report something?

Comment: One could open with “This [letter/memo] is to report/announce …” but why not simply omit that formula?

Comment: Sorry. I am not so clear. Do you mean I can say "This is to report/ announce"? Or do you mean I have to put 'letter' or "memo" after "This"?

Comment: @Alan, In a letter you can say, "I am writing to report..." (or "let you know" or "advise you" or "announce" or whatever). In a report or memo, just say the thing. People know that a report is meant to report and a memo is meant to memorandize.